# Trackpad switch pages with 3 fingers

Tags: trackpad, multi-touch, macos

By default the Back/Next gesture works with two fingers (in e.g. Safari) on the trackpad. Now it often happens to me when scrolling through iframes (with two fingers) I accidentally activate the back gesture. Now I changed it in settings to 3 fingers, but the animation is gone, and in Safari it's not anymore like dragging the page before from the left to center but like hitting the back-button (without animation)... Is it possible to use the real 2-fingers gesture with 3-fingers?

Answer (score 3):

No.

All you can have is to activate both the 2-finger and the 3-finger gestures. They work differently, though.

With two fingers you scroll the page to the sides revealing the page "below" it or the page "above" it according to the tag history.

With three fingers you just tell the browser to "go back" (swipe left) or "go forward" (swipe right) without any animation at all. At least this 3-finger gesture is consistent in many apps, including Finder.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But there is no program or something like that which could change it? (Like MagicPrefs for more Mouse and Trackpad features)...
Otherwise I'll have to use it without animation...
The problem is just, that I often use phpmyadmin for MySQL databases, and the create table forms are within an iframe and you often have to sroll to the left and right. So you have to scroll really careful, if you are at the very end of the iframe and continue scrolling it goes back in the history and all changes are lost.

Comment: In that case, why don't you just disable the 2-finger gesture? And about tools to change the behavior, I don't have a clue.

Answer (score 1):

If you download a program. But you should use 2 fingers. This is because you can use 3 fingers to move between desktop screens. I hope you take advantage of that awesome feature. you know mission control and screens

Comment: True, one could adapt and use the 3-finger method to change desktops. But I miss consistency in Apps using this new 2-finger gesture. So far mainly Preview and Safari use it.

Comment: I changed the gesture for moving between desktops to 4 fingers, so that's not the problem. Yes, I know Mission Control and Screens, really cool features.